# How to Increase Azure Application Insights Rate Limits

Tags: azure-application-insights, rate-limiting

My squad is building a Grafana dashboard that uses a custom datasource plugin https://github.com/vistaprint/Application-Insights-Datasource-Plugin which queries Azure Application Insights APIs.
We have discovered that there is a limit on max number of API requests https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/Rate-limits:
* Throttling limit: no more than 15 requests can be made in a minute across all API paths (/metrics, /events and /query), and
* Daily cap: no more than 1500 requests per day (UTC day) per API key can be made across all API paths.

We're worried that 1500 requests per day may not be enough, especially if the dashboard is refreshed frequently and accessed by many users. We wonder if there is a way to increase that limit.

Answer (score 0):

the next section of the [article you linked](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/Rate-limits) states:

> **Limits when using Azure Active Directory authentication**
>
> If using the
>   Azure API and Azure Active Directory for per user authentication, the
>   throttling limit is 60 requests per minute per user and *there is no
>   daily cap.* [emphasis added]

if you need higher than what the API Key auth allows, you'll need to look at using AAD auth instead.